# Add combo box dynamically in MS Access forms

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to create a form in MS access.
Initially i will have only one combo box.
My requirement is i have "Add" button if i click on this button this should dynamically add Combo boxes one below another.

My actual requirement is as follows:
I designed this form like tender reply form

Usually a tender will have date, Item descriptions, quantity etc....

I have got this date using date() function.
But this Item descriptions are already in database but there may be situations to add new item to database . I have to fetch from it or add into it if its new.

Am i clear with my explanations? Please help guys

exact thing i want is : wanna use a combo box for both, to add to database as well to fetch from database.

but inserting value to DB from combo box should not delete old record

Thanks,
Shanmugam

Comment: As @HansUp says, it is an unusual thing to want to do, unless you are creating your own wizard. It can be useful to say what problem you wish to solve, because someone may suggest a lateral solution that is easier to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [CreateControl Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa221167%28office.11%29.aspx) with *acComboBox* (value = 111) as control type.

If you want the new combo box to appear below the last, you'll need to determine the position of the last one so you can then compute the appropriate *.left* and *.top* properties for the new one.

But there will be considerably more overhead to create a combo at runtime.  In order for it to be useful, you will need to set a host of other properties, including: Row Source Type; Row Source; Bound Column; Control Source (if it will be a bound combo); Column Count; Column Widths.  And probably still more.  This task is more complicated than it may seem at first blush, and there are many opportunities for errors.

Personally, I've never found a situation where it seemed worth the effort.  But I don't mean to imply it doesn't make sense in your situation.

Comment: I don't understand your goal.  I did read the changes you made to the question, but it didn't help my understanding.

Comment: HansUp: please try to help me out now

Comment: I can't.  Best I can suggest is to submit a new question; this one is no longer about dynamically adding a combo to a form (seems to me).  Then maybe someone will see the unanswered question and figure out how to help you.